# Are both bobince's the same?

Tags: support, status-completed, users

There's a [high rep version](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) and a [low rep version](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16756/bobince).

Comment: Man! Suddenly it's Bobince Hour on meta. :-) Yes, the Other Bobince was an anonymous me, before I lost the cookie and signed up with a proper OpenID. I didn't think it was important enough to merit pestering the ♦ for a merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say so. The gravatar and website match, plus the low-rep user is unregistered and came before the high-rep one. This probably means that he lost the cookies to that account and had to create another one.

I recommed that a mod on SO merge the accounts.

Comment: Send up the lizard signal

Comment: @Joel: ok, I flagged one of his posts on SO